# How to avoid header truncation on the tiff using GhostScript. Convert ps to tiff

Tags: linux, shell, header, tiff, postscript

In this section I add the header file to the top of the tiff file.

```
echo "/CourierLatin1 findfont 8 scalefont setfont" >>${PS}
echo "40 2 moveto (${DATE}) show" >>${PS}
echo "200 2 moveto (${NAME}) show" >>${PS}
echo "400 2 moveto (${FROM}) show" >>${PS}
echo "510 2 moveto (${PAGEINFO}) show showpage" >>${PS}

${BIN}/gs -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sOutputFile=${HDR_FILE} \
    -dDEVICEWITHPOINTS=612 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=11 ${PS} >>${LOG_FILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    cleanup
    echo "${BIN}/gs failed" >>${LOG_FILE}
    exit 1
fi

# Overlay the header onto the tiff page
SIZE=`${BIN}/tiffinfo ${f} | grep "Image Width:" | sed -e "s/Image Width//" | sed -e "s/Image Length//" | sed -e "s/ //g"`
WIDTH=`echo ${SIZE} | cut -d: -f2`
LENGTH=`echo ${SIZE} | cut -d: -f3`
OFFSET=`expr ${LENGTH} - 2156`
# no shifting of header line up or down is needed
OFFSET=0
if [ ${OFFSET} -lt 0 ] ; then
    OFFSET=0
fi
echo "Adding ${HDR_FILE} to ${f} ${WIDTH}x${LENGTH} at 0,${OFFSET}" >>${LOG_FILE}
${CONVERT} tiff:${f} -draw "image over 0,${OFFSET} 0,0 'tiff:${HDR_FILE}'" -compress Group4 -flatten +matte tiff:${f} >>${LOG_FILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    cleanup
    echo "${CONVERT} failed" >>${LOG_FILE}
    exit 1
fi
```

Can come to me in any size page. So I first translate tiff post script to size.

I convert tiff again. Can see the code as below:

```
# Nasty compromise - Have to convert the tiff file to ps file so that I can turn around
# and create a 'faxable' tiff file (one that Radisys will accept)
${BIN}/tiff2ps -a -h11.0 -w8.5 ${LOCAL_FILE} >${PS_FILE}
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    cleanup
    echo "${BIN}/tiff2ps failed" >>${LOG_FILE}
    exit 1
fi

# Part 2 of compromise
${BIN}/gs -dQUIET -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=tiffg4 -sPAPERSIZE=letter -r204x196 -sOutputFile=${LOCAL_FILE} ${PS_FILE} >>${LOG_FILE} 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
    cp ${BKUP_FILE} ${ORIG_FILE}
    cleanup
    echo "${BIN}/gs ps2tiff failed" >>${LOG_FILE}
    exit 1
fi
```

Output tiff is given the Radisys. I dont understand Why header cut for this output.pdf.

You can see output fax image as below. why is Header cutted ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you are printing the 'header' first, then putting the image from the TIFF file (in this case, the text 'FAX') on top of it.

TIFF files aren't masks, so the white space is not transparent. When you turn a TIFF file into PostScript it encapsulates the TIFF bitmap image as a PostScript image. Where the white space in the image lies on top of the 'header', it prints over it, obscuring part of the 'header'.

Its a little hard to be sure what's going on, I'm not a shell script expert, but it appears you first use Ghostscript to render a piece of PostScript to TIFF. That is your 'header'.

You then invoke $(CONVERT) which I'm going to guess is ImageMagick's convert utility to combine the header and some original TIFF file.

I suspect at this point is where your problem occurs, I'm guessing that you need to put the two tiff files in the reverse order so that the header is placed 'on top' of the original, instead of 'under' it (in Z-order terms. In your invocation of $(CONVERT) try swapping $(f) and $(HDR_FILE).

You can of course check the TIFF file at that point, presumably, to see if all is well.

You then take that TIFF file, use tiff2ps (which I think is part of libtiff) to wrap the image up as PostScript, and then use Ghostscript to re-render the image at a different (fax) resolution.

I'd say that you are using the wrong tool for that last step anyway. You already have a bitmap, you'd be better off using an image manipulation application to downsample it to the desired resolution. While your solution undoubtedly works, I would suspect that something like ImageMagick would do a better job.

At the very least, checking the TIFF file before you send it through tiff2ps should tell you whether the result is correct at that point.

Comment: Yes, your guess is right. I try to "In your invocation of $(CONVERT) try swapping $(f) and $(HDR_FILE).". but it is not work. I use  only to add the header this file. The tiff file at the end of the file is correct. but I give the tiff file to radisys then it gives me a broken. and I do not know why I got corrupted. @KenS

Comment: Well,  how do I reduce the pixel size of my fax file ? @KenS

Comment: Use ImageMagick perhaps ?